# Webpack error TS2339: Property 'dialog' does not exist on type 'JQuery'

Tags: javascript, jquery, typescript, webpack

My webpack.config.js is

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'AdminPanel/AdminPanel': '../../client/scripts/AdminPanel/AdminPanel.ts',
        'Registration/Registration': '../../client/scripts/Registration/Registration.ts'
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: '../../src/client/scripts'
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.webpack.js', '.web.js', '.ts', '.js']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' },
            { test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" },
            { test: /\.(woff|woff2|eot|ttf|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader' },
            { test: /bootstrap\/dist\/js\/umd\//, loader: 'imports?jQuery=jquery' },
            { test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif)$/i, loader: "file-loader" }
        ]
    }
}
```

contents of **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "test",
  "main": "src/server.js",
  "author": {
    "name": "pratik"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^0.0.33",
    "@types/bootstrap": "^3.3.5",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.3.30",
    "@types/express": "^4.0.35",
    "@types/express-handlebars": "0.0.29",
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.40",
    "@types/jqueryui": "^1.11.32",
    "@types/mysql": "0.0.31",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.1",
    "file-loader": "^0.10.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "ts-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.7",
    "webpack": "^2.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.16.1",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "express": "^4.14.1",
    "express-handlebars": "^3.0.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "jqueryui": "^1.11.1",
    "mysql": "^2.13.0"
  }
}
```

My ts file

```
import * as $ from 'jquery';
import 'jqueryui/jquery-ui.js';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
import 'jqueryui/jquery-ui.css';

$(document).ready(function () {
    alert('hi');
    let s = '<input class="date" type= "date" name= "txtFromUniversityDate" id= "txtFromUniversityDate" placeholder= "Please select joining date." > </p>';
    $('.container').dialog();
});
```

To generate the compiled version, I am running below command:

**`tsc && webpack --config "../../webpack.config.js" --display-error-details --verbose --watch`**

But I am running into below error:

***ERROR in /client/scripts/AdminPanel/AdminPanel.ts
(9,21): error TS2339: Property 'dialog' does not exist on type 'JQuery'.***

Can anyone please help me in resolving the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's bug in the webpack or it may be a feature. I am posting an answer here just in case somebody needs it in future. Adding a reference to **d.ts** at the top of the file same as module reference resolved the issue.

```
/// <reference path="../../../node_modules/@types/jqueryui/index.d.ts" />
```

Same goes for all the external js files.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install TypeScript definitions for jQuery UI.